# problems with getting value from SharedPreferences

Tags: android

i have this code i call from a service.

```
   prefs = getSharedPreferences(homeConfigure.APP_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   city = prefs.getString(CITY + appWidgetId,"nothing");
```

it returns the correct value stored. but subsequent calls to the service through an AlarmManager in the service class returns the value "nothing".

what could be wrong?

i save them in the homeConfigure activity like this:

```
city = cityText.getText().toString();    
Editor editor = prefs.edit();   
editor.putString(CITY + appWidgetId,city);  
editor.commit();
```

and the appwidget is obtained from an intent in the onCreate() of the configuration class when the widget is first added:

```
appWidgetId = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using getDefaultPreferences(context) instead.

Comment: it doesn't seem to work. i did prefs = preferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreference(homeConfigure.self). where self is self = this; in the homeConfigure Class. but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Rexx how do you initialize your appWidgetId and CITY?

Comment: not sure what you mean but as i said, its from a configuration activity. my appWidgetId(ApPWidgetManager.Extra_APPWIDGET_ID) is gotten from an intent and the CITY is from an EditText. i have added how i save them in the question

Comment: i have added the following code above. i hope thats what you wete asking about.